# Can't get JSON from external service even using JSONP

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

Hi I'm trying to use json data from a site, but I'm unable to do it with jsonp, not sure if I'm coding something wrong or it's the service.

```
   <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#frmInstrumento").submit(function(event) {
            alert("hello");
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://www.camaradenegocios.com/api/get/",
                // The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
                jsonp: "promotions",

                // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
                dataType: "jsonp",

                // Work with the response
                success: function( response ) {
                    alert(response);
                    console.log( response ); // server response
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The url to work with is https://www.camaradenegocios.com/api/get/promotions I can see the data if I browse, but can't consume it with Jquery.

Comment: Please put the error attribute after the success attribute and give it a console.log() or a alert() to show the error, then report.

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.camaradenegocios.com/api/get/. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have included the jQuery library. If not, please do so by having something like this in your HTML page header:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

I think if you try to get JSON data instead of JSONP, it should work. Replacing your code with the one mentioned below will work as expected, fetching the response array that we see when we browse the URL.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#frmInstrumento").submit(function(event) {
        alert("hello");
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.camaradenegocios.com/api/get/promotions",
            // The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service

            // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSON
            dataType: "json",

            // Work with the response
            success: function( response ) {
                alert(response);
                console.log( response ); // server response
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Now `response` will have the raw response, you will have to stringify it to have it in readable format. Also you can play with this response as an object and extract attributes and members from it.

Comment: Yes, I did. Got this: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.camaradenegocios.com/api/get/promotions. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Comment: Not working, this is driving me crazy. Provider gave me this: https://www.camaradenegocios.com/app_dev.php/api/get/promotions and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON) ; response appear to be `JSON` , not `JSONP`

```js
$.getJSON("https://www.camaradenegocios.com/api/get/promotions"
, function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: what's the callback param for ? URL isn't returning jsonp

Comment: @charlietfl You are correct . See updated post ; removed unnecessary `?callback=` from url ;

Answer (score 0):

now I got it to work, not sure what was wrong with provider, anyways. Also I was reading about submit, since it does a postback it doesn't retrieve the data.

```
  $(function(){
      loadData = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.camaradenegocios.com/api/get/promotions',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(response){ 
                $.each(response, function(key, data) {
                    alert(key);
                    $.each(data, function (index, data) {
                        console.log('index', data);
                        alert(data);
                    })
                })      
            }
        });    
      };

      loadData();
  });
```

Now only I have to parse the data correctly.

Thanks.